# Find func extremum for the given condition

Tags: calculus, extreme-value-analysis

Find so-called conditional extremum attained by $f(x,y,z)=x \cdot y \cdot z;$ under the following condition: $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$.
It is thought that solution would rely on Lagrange multipliers method.

Can you help me with this one? I have no idea of how to solve it wisely.

Comment: Yes you can use Lagrange multipliers (or you can argue via symmetry to avoid all that, or use symmetry as a sanity check on the answers you get). To set up Lagrange, you have $\nabla f = (yz,xz,xy)^T$ and $\nabla g = (2x, 2y, 2z)^T$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani And what stands here for $\nabla f, \nabla g$?

Comment: The gradients of $f$ and $g$ where $g$ is the constraint function. If you've used Lagrange multipliers before, you know that the condition is stated as $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ (or potentially using $Df$ and $Dg$ instead if you're more familiar with that).

Comment: Oh, I got it, however in my way of solution, I have to check the case of $\lambda=0$, which would took lots and lots of time, I was hoping there is a better solution..

Comment: Well $\lambda = 0$ is the case where you have unconstrained optimization so it's not a relevant case here since $f$ has no local extrema at all, the only critical point then is $(x,y,z) = 0$ which is a saddle.

Comment: And would you mind providing full solution? I got that point (x,y,z)=0 as extrema, however not sure if I have checked every case..

Comment: Sure I will, also I realized my comment about $(0,0,0)$ being the only point when $\lambda = 0$ wasn't entirely true.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try to redo my solution too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we begin, note by symmetry that we expect the answers to be symmetric in $x,y,z$ by which I mean that if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point where we have an extrema, then so is any permutation of it. This will be a sanity check on our answer.

I have $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ and $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a^2 = 0$. The condition is $Df = \lambda Dg$ which is restated as
$$(yz, xz, xy) = \lambda (2x, 2y, 2z)$$
I am going to proactively note some technicalities but in reality when solving this problem, you would have to deal with them as and when they pop up. We note two things:

1. What happens when $\lambda = 0$? Well we have $xz = yz = xy = 0$. It is tempting to say that the only point that satisfies this is $(0,0,0)$ but this is not true. $(l,0,0), (0,m,0) \text{ & } (0,0,n)$ all satisfy these equations. But these are the only solutions. Great, now plugging these into the constraint equation gives us $6$ points to keep in mind: $(±a,0,0), (0,±a,0), (0,0,±a)$. At all these points, $f = 0$.
2. Now we can proceed with the assumption that $\lambda \neq 0$. This actually forces all of $x,y,z$ to be non-zero. Let's see why. WLOG, say $z= 0 $. Then we get $(0,0,xy) = \lambda(2x, 2y, 0)$ This gives us that $x= 0, y = 0$, which is not a point that satisfies the constraint.

Great, now we can proceed to solving this quite easily. A common trick with a single constraint Lagrange multiplier is to eliminate $\lambda$ by "dividing" one vector by another. What I mean by this is to write
$$\frac{yz}{x} = \frac{xz}{y} = \frac{xy}{z}$$
These fractions are okay because of point $2$ above. WLOG I'm going to choose the first two to work with.
$$\frac{yz}{x} = \frac{xz}{y} \implies y^2z = x^2z \implies y^2 = x^2 \implies y = ±x$$
Similarly, we see that $x, y$ and $z$ are all the same up to a sign. This is exactly our symmetry hunch that we had in the beginning. So the constraint becomes $3x^2 = a^2$ or $x = ±\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$. So our $8$ solutions are $(±\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}, ±\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}, ±\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}})$ where you take all possible combinations of the $±$. Now the last step is to evaluate $f$ at all these points. There are only two values of $f$ possible, which are $\frac{a^3}{\sqrt{27}}$ and $-\frac{a^3}{\sqrt{27}}$ and so these are the constrained extrema.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks

Comment: However, not sure, whether $a \neq 0$ here. Seems that here it is used several times, also what is finally done with points from the case $\lambda = 0$, what it gives us that there $f(x,y,z)=0$?

Comment: Well if $a \neq 0$ then the set only contains one point $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ so that point is trivially the minimum and the maximum. And I didn't do anything with those points since we have values of $f$ both greater and lesser than it, so it's neither a global minimum nor maximum.

Comment: And is that sufficient condition to ignore them?

Comment: If you're looking for the maxima and minima, then the answer will be the maximum and minimum value right? Clearly $0$ is neither the maximum or minimum. I'm not ignoring it per se, it's just (according to your question) not something you're looking for.

Comment: However it just have to be local max/min)

Comment: Ooh, I've understood, I've forgotten to mention that in the question, I'm so sorry, the task was to find local ones

Comment: The concept of local max and min doesn't make sense in constrained optimization. There are only absolute maxima and minima (which are really just called maxima and minima in this case, you can leave the absolute out). Regardless, Lagrange gives you absolute maxima and minima, so in this case this is definitely the answer.